# Python3 - Cannot read docx, odt file - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, file, encoding, utf-8, decode

I am trying to split a large docx file into small files. For that when reading a file in **python3.6** with the following code.

```
with open('h.docx', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
```

It throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 
  10: invalid continuation byte
```

h.docx is created using LibreOffice Calc with just `'hello world'` in it as content. I can read this successfully in Python 2.7 without any errors.

I tried

```
with open('h.docx', 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    a = f.read()
```

In this I can read the file without any errors. But when written to another file, the original contents are lost.

Also tried `errors='surrogateescape'`, but when written to another file the original contents are lost.

Comment: What do you want to do? If you just want to read and write to another file, read it with "rb" `with open('h.docx', 'rb') as f:` and write it with `wb`

Comment: I am trying to read a large docx file and want to split it into small multiple files. So I think I cannot read the file as binary here.

Comment: .docx files are binary files, so you have to open them with "rb". Also, if you are going to split the whole  blob into pieces, you won't get anything useful. The .docx files are actually compressed archives. Try this: change the file extension to .zip and open it with an archive utility, then you will be able to see what's in there. The text is embedded in some XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment. What you are doing is just non-sense: you are trying to read a ".docx" file as if it was a text file which it is **not**. It is a complex format where several xml files (and possibly others...) are concatenated into a single zip file. You should not even contemplate processing such a file *by hand* unless:

- trivial changes such as replacing a word with another one
- read-only operation such as researching a particular string
- you want to write an docx processing package (good luck with it)

and even those would not be simple operation.

What is possible:

- process the file as a binary file when you only see it as an opaque content, for example to send it over a network connection
- use a dedicated library like [python-docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx)
- under Windows, use the automation interface of Word to have word itself process the file ([comtypes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) could help here)

Comment: Quick question: Why can I do the same in Python2.7 and not in Python3.6? I can read the docx file in python2.7 without any errors.

Comment: Python 2 strings are just byte strings, that means that in Python 2 you cannot have unicode decode errors when reading a text file because no unicode decode operation is involved. But you are likely to get unusable garbage because you could still have problems in processing null of `'\x1D'` (carriage return) characters.

Comment: @SergeBallesta while you offer some good insight here, thinking it may be a bit more helpful to not start by telling someone what they're "doing is just non-sense". This statement is degrading and inflammatory ya?

Comment: @dgg: I try hard to never be offensive on SO. What I meant was that trying to process binary files with text tools is a recipe for disappointment, and disaster if used on production data. I just wanted to tell OP that they were using the wrong tool and urge them to search a different way.