# python : how to split big .docx file by some repetitive keyword

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want split .docx file into small .docx file on the basis of some repetitive keywords. like, my file is having data...

### ABCD:

kjndlndflf 
jfnkajnfak 
kjnflanlkl 
fwefagasdg

### ABCD:

adnclwk
asdafvdfv
afersdf

### ABCD:

sdfqerf
rfwer
erer

i want to copy contents within two "ABCD" till end into different files with name ABCD1...ABCD(n).

my code is

```
def writeFiles():
  '''User defined string to search and split the doc, Doc will get
     split after searching this string as a starting line for the 
     doc till one line before the string appers again'''

    feature = input (" Please provide the Feature ID \n : ")  /*asking keyword from user

  #Asking user to select desired file 
    print ("Please select file to split")

    path=get_path();  /*function for file browsing



    i =1;
    document = Document(docx=path)      
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
      if feature in paragraph.text:
        document.add_paragraph()
        document.add_page_break()
        name = feature+repr(i)+".docx"
        document.save(name);
        i= i+1;
```

the code is making and copying complete data 'N' number of files if the file is having keyword 'N' number of times but not copying data between two repetitive keywords.

Below code is now splitting the file with keyword but the format, fonts and tables are not coming

```
try:
    if feature in paragraph.text:
      name = feature + repr(i) + ".docx"
      i = i + 1
      doc.add_paragraph(paragraph.text.split(feature)[0])
      doc.save(name);
      doc = Document()
      doc.add_paragraph(paragraph.text.split(feature)[1])

else:
      doc.add_paragraph(paragraph.text)
```

please help me out......

Comment: format of your code does not look right, i.e. no indentation after for loop and if statment.

Comment: i have done the changes, is it ok now?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536461/python3-cannot-read-docx-odt-file-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-d)

Comment: thanks for link...but still after using binary and ZIP operation, i am not able to split the file. I am not a professional in python so what is possible at my level i am doing.